# How to continue with the execution even if i catch an error

Tags: python, error-handling

I want to control the error just printing it but continuing with the rest, por example:

```
try:
 list =('a',2,3,5,6,'b',8)

 print(list[8])
 print("continue execution")
except:
  print("An exception occurred")
```

It just will print the error but not the continue execution, is possible to continue even after exception?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it's a bad idea to reassign builtin names like `list`.  It's doubly bad here because you're not even assigning it to a list, you're assigning it to a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

What is missing and you're looking for is the `finally` instruction.
Syntax:

```
try:
    #search for errors
except:
    #if errors found, run this code
finally:
    #run this code no matter if errors found or not, after the except block
```

The `finally` block contains the code that will be run after the `except` block, no matter if errors were raised or not.

Answer (score 2):

See if this rearrangement of your own code helps:

```
list =('a',2,3,5,6,'b',8)

try:
 print(list[8])
except:
  print("An exception occurred")

print("continue execution")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it matters for you to "print continue" right after exception occurrence , then you can put whatever you want to do before exception in a "bool function" and  then inside the "try" check if function succeed or not.it means "if error occurred continue ,else show "An exception occurred".

```py
try:
    assert doStuff() == False
    print("continue execution")
except:
    print("An exception occurred")
```

Comment: Better to use `is` instead of `==` with `True` and `False`.